# Can 法王（ほうおう） mean anyone besides the Pope?

Tags: words, religion

I know this word can refer to the the Pope, the head of the Roman Catholic church, but when I tried looking it up on google images, in addition to the Pope, I also saw the Dalai Lama, and some other people I did not recognize.  Can the word have meanings besides Pope?

Answer (score 3):

法王 is an originally Chinese Buddhist term, originally referring to monks and religious rulers who followed the laws of Buddhism (hence the literal translation, law-king). In modern times, this title has been expanded to refer to religious leaders of other religions, including Christianity.

Source: [法王 (Wikipedia)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%95%E7%8E%8B)